# Create a new filename upon each line from a file

Tags: python

I could open the file "setup.conf", replace the text from  "Hostname=server" to "Hostname=server2" and save it as "setup2.conf".

But, I want that **each line from "list.txt" becomes the name of the new file, instead of "setup2.conf".**

Content of "list.txt":

```
server1
server2
server3
```

For example of what I did to read each line:

```
fh = open('list.txt')
while True:
    line = fh.readline()
    print(line)
    if not line:
        break
fh.close()
```

Sample of what I did to replace a text and save the file:

```
fin = open("setup.conf", "rt")
fout = open("setup2.conf", "wt")

for line in fin:
    fout.write(line.replace('Hostname=server1', 'Hostname=server2'))

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a new file for each read line, then write to it. For example

```
with open('list.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        server = line.rstrip()
        with open(server + ".conf", "w") as fout, open("setup.conf") as setup:
            for line in setup:
                fout.write(line.replace("Hostname=server1", "Hostname=" + server)
                fout.write("\n")
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working yet 
```
with open('list.txt') as fh:
    i = 1
    for line in fh:
        with open(line.rstrip()) as fout:
            fout.write(str(i) + "\n")
            i += 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open(line.rstrip()) as fout:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'content1'

Comment: Oops, forgot to open file in write mode

Comment: I would like to change the "Hostname=server" of setup.conf to the servername from list.txt

Comment: I don't understand the question, then. You're trying to create 3 files? Or replace the contents of one file?